Collecting Axes using plot_layout() in Patchwork: Aligning and Plotting Sediment Core Images and Downhole Logs
Using a combination of ggplot2, magick, and patchwork, I've gotten pretty close to getting a programmatic sediment core downhole log plot with a scaled photograph aligned along the left y-axis. See the current result below along with data and code. The remaining issue I have is removing the depth y axis between the image and the data plot. Patchwork seems to be able to do this using: plot_layout(axes = "collect_y"), however, I am unable to get it working correctly.
I should note that what I'm doing here trying to mix a scaled imaged and a plot seems a bit of an unusual case for these packages. Where am I going wrong? Is there perhaps a better way to be creating a plot like this in R?
Here is what I am currently able to obtain:

Here is broadly what I'm shooting for:

Sample Data Are located here: Sample Data
# Load Required Packages
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(magick)

# Read in plot data
data <- read.csv(file = "Data/data.csv")

# Plotting ----
## L* and b* in log format
logplot <- ggplot(data) +
  geom_path(aes(x=value, y=depth)) +
  ylim(1.2,0) +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  labs(title='Core 10004_6A_1_2') +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(metric), scales = 'free_x')

## Read in RGB plot image
plotimg <- "Data/10004_6A_1_2.png"
image<-image_read(plotimg)
raster<-as.raster(image)

## Plot Core Image
image <- ggplot(data,aes(x,depth)) + 
  scale_y_reverse() +
  ylim(1.2,0) +
  xlim(0,0.044) +
  coord_flip() + 
  coord_fixed(expand = TRUE) +
  annotation_raster(raster, 0, 0.044, -1.182, 0)
image

## Patchwork Plots
(image | logplot) + plot_layout(axes = "collect_y") & ylim(1.2, 0)


logplot <- logplot + theme(
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    plot.margin=margin(0,0,0,0)
  )

image <- image + theme(
  axis.title.x = element_blank(),
  axis.text.x = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
  plot.margin=margin(0,0,0,0)
)


